# ORA-22275 error: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a procedure that populates a BLOB variable with a PDF document. What I am trying to do is add logic to only display the PDF document within a 60 day period from a static date. See below:

```
check_staticdate     number(1); 

function DisplayPDF (audit in number) RETURN blob is

person_id     person.person_id%type;
z_lob         blob;
blob_length   NUMBER;


CURSOR getPDF(audit number) IS
   select report
   from report_table
   where report_type = 'PDF'
   and job_no = audit order by rec_no;


begin

/* Check Valid ID */
if not package.ValidID(person_id, check_only=>TRUE) then
   return z_lob;
end if;


/* Here is the case statement.*/
select case
   when exists
      (
       SELECT 'x' from table
       where table_id = person_id
       and trunc(sysdate) < trunc(table_static_date + 60)
      )

    then 1
    else 0
   end into check_staticdate
from dual;


if (check_staticdate = 0) then
   return z_lob;
end if;



open getPDF(audit);
fetch getPDF into z_lob;
close getPDF;
return z_lob;


end DisplayPDF;
```

The error I am receiving is: `ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified.`

I am new to Oracle SQL, and am unsure why my ValidID check works by returning z_lob but my case statement does not.

**Edit: Adding full error stack**

```
Failed to execute target procedure ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

ORA-06512: at "SYS.WPG_DOCLOAD", line 51

ORA-06512: at "User.Package", line 733

ORA-06512: at line 33
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Initialise your lob with temporary first

```
DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(z_lob,true); --true if you want it to be cached.
```

Comment: I wanted to make sure you got credit for this. This ended up getting reassigned and re-prioritized. However, your answer ultimately worked. Thanks!

Comment: Along with `DBMS_LOB.OPEN`, like that - 
`DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(
      lob_loc => z_lob
    , cache   => true
    , dur     => dbms_lob.call);
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(
      lob_loc    => z_lob
    , open_mode  => DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);`
- and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is probably returning (depending on your `audit` parameter value) a blob with a NULL value to the `SYS.WPG_DOCLOAD` method which throws the unhandled exception you see.

Perhaps you could modify your `return z_lob;` to be `return nvl(z_lob, empty_blob());`